# Scraping data from an audio analyzer application

Tags: debugging, c++, memory

Briefly:

I have an app that analyzes audio files and classifies them into 4 or 5 categories, how would one go about scraping the category each audio file belongs to? What is a good place to start?

Details:

It's a Mac x86 app but probably compiled with cross-platform frameworks, as it is available for Windows as well with the same UI.

I run “strings” on the binary and the name “juce” came up a few times, which is a C++ framework.

The info about the audio files is not displayed on a table, but as scattered points on a 2-D plane, similar sounds get placed together, and sounds of the same category are points of the same color. But still there must be an array in memory with the info I want to get.

Comment: A surprising number of graphical frameworks are built upon message passing.  As a result, many of them have facilities for tapping into the message stream to help diagnose problems.  I'd probably try to identify the graphics framework, and then on its developer page, see if it has diagnostic logging capabilities you can turn on, or whether it has APIs for letting you see the message traffic.